# Automatic Localization in symfony2

Tags: symfony

Please look at the following code:

```
public function __construct($error_code)
{
    $translator = new Translator('en');
    $translator->addLoader('yaml', new YamlFileLoader());
    $translator->addResource('yaml', dirname(__DIR__).'/Resources/translations/messages.en.yml', 'en');
    $this->setErrorCode($translator->trans($error_code));
}
```

I am new to symfony. I have created a class MyProjectExceptions which extends Exception. Now when I have to throw a custom exception I call this class where I get the $error_code. Now this $error_code is a constant of another class which has its locale in MyBundle/Resources/transalations/messages.en.yml which will be used to throw as exception message.

Now my question are following:

- How can I avoid addResource, so it can automatically add it based on Locale and find the string?
- How to access serviceContainer in this class so that I can access session to set and get locales OR other services.
- Can we set the default Loader as well.

In above code I am creating an instance of Translator class and manually passing 'en'. but it should pick default locale or user set locale.
I tried many solutions but not able to get the desired results.

Any help would be appreciated. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

You need to register your class as Symfony service. Read the documentation: http://symfony.com/doc/current/book/service_container.html#creating-configuring-services-in-the-container

After that you can inject other services (like Translation) in your constructor. It will use all parameters that you have already set.

If you inject translator service it will pick the parameters that you have already set. For example, if you defined parameters for translator (including default locale) at `config.yml`, then you overrode this locale with parameter in route, you will get translator service set up with this locale. And it will automatically use resources that are lied in appropriate directories.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. But its only partially answered. My main problem is I don't want to addResource manually. I want it to pick up automatically based on user locale.

Comment: If you inject translator service it will pick the parameters that you have already set. For example, if you defined parameters for translator (including default locale) at config.yml, then you overrode this locale with parameter in route, you will get translator service with this locale. And it will automatically use resources that are lied in appropriate directories.